# Does null coalescing operator cache the result in c#

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I know that doing `(myValue ?? new SomeClass())` is similar to `(myValue == null ? new SomeClass() : myValue)`

But out of curiosity, is there any performance benefit when I call a function, say 
`(getResult() ?? new SomeClass())`. Will `getResult()` get executed twice? It seems unintuitive since I've specified the method call only once.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208067/operators-instead-of-ifelse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431064/what-is-operator-in-c

Comment: above two are great answer, explaining ?? . Please have a look.

Comment: @Mukund - both explain what a coalescing operator does, but do not answer the question of whether the expression is evaluated once\twice. (hamid's answer in the second one seems to indicate twice but I don't believe it is correct simply because he was just trying to explain what it does, not what is generated in the IL).. It will be easy enough to test using a static counter, but I'd rather hear it from an expert ;-)

Comment: The premise of this question is incorrect.  The null coalescing operator does not expand to a conditional expression.

Comment: @phoog - I'm aware of that. By "expands" I meant "is equivalent to". Fixed it though, thanks!

Comment: @arviman but that's just it.  It is *not* equivalent, precisely because it does not evaluate the first expression more than once.

Comment: @phoog - you're confusing functional equivalency with implementation details. We're referring only to semantics...the "what", not "how".

Comment: @arviman As far as I see it, you are the one confusing functional equivalency with implementation details.  `A ?? B` is not functionally equivalent to `A == null ? B : A` precisely because they are different in terms of side effects.  `A ?? B` is functionally equivalent to `var temp = A; temp == null ? B : A`.

Comment: @phoog I get your point. But, how else was I supposed to communicate the similarity between null coalescing and conditional when I was not aware of the background implementation. (just a rhetorical question)

Comment: @arviman point taken.  I just read your question as "I know X is true, so is X false?" where X is false, so the opening sentence of the question is a contrafactual assumption.  I realize your question is rhetorical but I'll answer it anyway: I would probably just have asked "is the left operand of the `??` operator executed twice when its result is non-null" although somewhat more verbosely.  But that's after this whole discussion.  Phrasing a question from scratch can be difficult, I agree.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if by "caching" you mean storing it in a temporary variable, then yes.

This construct:

```
var result = (getResult() ?? new SomeClass());
```

can be thought of to be equivalent to this:

```
var <temp> = getResult();
if (<temp> == null)
    <temp> = new SomeClass();
result = <temp>;
```

This also tells you that the second part, the operand after `??` isn't executed at all if the first operand is not `null`.

So to answer your concrete questions:

1. Each operand is evaluated at most once
2. The second operand is only evaluated if the first one evaluates to `null`

Note also that you can chain these:

```
var result = first() ?? second() ?? third() ?? fourth();
```

Which results in:

1. Evaluates `first()`
2. If `first()` evaluated to `null`, evaluates `second()`
3. If `second()` evaluated to `null` as well, evaluates `third()`
4. If all of the above evaluated to `null`, finally evaluates `fourth`

The result is the first (no pun intended) non-null value returned.

---

This type of code is about to get even better in new C# with the new `?.` operator:

```
var result = first?.second?.third;
```

This is basic `.` handling, ie. it will read the `second` member of `first`, and then the `third` member of whatever `second` is, but it will stop at the first `null`, and will also make sure to evaluate each step only once:

```
(obj as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
```

`obj as IDisposable` will only evaluate once.

```
TryGetObjectToSave()?.Save();
```

Will only call `TryGetObjectToSave()` once, and if it returns something, the `Save()` method on that something will be called.